# Install CentOS 7.8 minimal into existing encrypted LVM with EFI boot failed

Tags: centos

Install CentOS into existing encrypted LVM with EFI boot failed.

I'm about to set up a laptop with both Kali Linux + CentOS.
First I installed Kali Linux and created a LVM with LUKS encryption. I used 50% of the space for Kali partition. I also create a centos partition with the other 50%.

In the CentOs graphical installation, the partition part finds and unlocks the LVM correctly, sees the centos partition and I can choose it+pick to reformat it and use as mounting point /

But I cannot end the step because CentOS DEMANDS to write EFI boot too. I tried to point it to the existing EFI partition which is formated for EFI but installation process shows me "cant install into LVM, cant install into ext2" and such bullshit. There is no ext2 partition present.

Any idea if i can skip the EFI installation part somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

CentOS likely requires a simple (none-LVM, unencrypted) `/boot` partition and from what you're saying you just have a EUFI system partition and the rest of your space is taken by LUKS+LVM which cannot be used for `/boot`.

Edit: I've just confirmed it.